# waypoints refresh not working when modifying a div

Tags: resize, height, refresh, jquery-waypoints

I have a site made of "slides" 100% height.

```
<div class="slide" id="one">page1</div>
<div class="slide" id="two">page2</div>
<div class="slide" id="three">page3</div>
```

I use waypoints to perform some animation based on the position of the scroll, and it works fine. The context used is "window" and below an example:

```
$('#one').waypoint(function(direction) 
{
//do something
}, { offset: '75%' });
```

By the way, in a slide there is a button that modifies the height of an image (it becomes very big), so after the resize the height of the container changes and also the height of the "slide", too.
I need the waypoint to refresh, in order to be raised at the same percentage calculated on the new size of the slide. I tried to do

```
$.waypoints('refresh');
```

after the resize, but it seems not working.

Below a piece of my css:

```
html {
height: 100%;

}

body{
text-align:center;
height:100%;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
}


.slide{
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
background: white;
min-height: 700px;
min-width: 1024px;
}


#home {
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
min-height: 800px;
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What you do in the `// do something` is very important. Can you update with specifics?